# hide div if it doesn't have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide a class if it doesn't have the class `active`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  if (!$('.active').hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).hide();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="subheader active">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Goodbye</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Hello Again</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the `subheader` that doesn't have the class `active`, use

```
$('.subheader:not(.active)').hide();
```

A better solution would be, I think, to use pure CSS for this:

```
.subheader {
  display: none;
}
.subheader.active {
  display: block;
}
```

As demonstrated in this snippet, that only uses jQuery to toggle the class, and uses CSS to decide what happens with it visually.

```js
$('.subheader').on('click', function(){
    $('.subheader').toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.subheader {
  display: none;
}
.subheader.active {
   display: block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="subheader active">
  <p>Hello, click to toggle</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Goodbye</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Hello Again</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function() {
    $('.subheader:not(.active)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="subheader active">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Goodbye</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Hello Again</p>
</div>
```

Or, with css:

```css
.subheader{ display: none; }
.subheader.active{ display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="subheader active">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Goodbye</p>
</div>
<div class="subheader">
  <p>Hello Again</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to hide divs with subheader class:

```
$('.subheader:not(.active)').hide();
```